# Changing title generated by PHP

Tags: php, class, tags, indexing, title

I have a small PHP based directory indexor on my site. One of the templates handles the title tag as follows:

```
<title>{info:dir}</title>
```

The generated title tag starts with "./" for instance "./dir1/dir2/and_so_on".
What I want is to get rid of the "./" at the begining.

The PHP classes are here: [removed]

Please advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template.php, line 121, replace with

```
 '{info:dir}'=>(isset($dir)?preg_replace('#^\./#','',Url::html_output($dir)):''),
```

if it **always** has `./` in front you could use also

```
 '{info:dir}'=>(isset($dir)?substr(Url::html_output($dir),2):''),
```

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to provide you with a proper answer without having more information. However, i've provided a few basic solutions below.

Assuming that the template engine you are using is Smarty (or something with similar syntax), you can replace the value of the title tag with the following:

```
<title>{info:dir|replace:'./':''}</title>
```

Alternatively, you can edit the template.php file and do a substr() or str_replace() on line 121.

I recommend making the change in the html template rather than the PHP file.

Comment: `{info:dir|replace:'./':''}` it is not Smarty, it is some self-written template engine.